# How to show arabic digit on button?

Tags: android, button, widget, arabic

I try to show arabic digits on bottun widget , i type text valu in arabic mode but it`s show english mode on bottun ! how can i do this ?
thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly the digits `0123456789` are [in fact Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). Do you mea [Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals), specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to set the background of your picture with the .gif, .png or .jpg of your arabic character via CSS like:

```
<input type="button" class="arabicChar" />
```

Then in your stylesheet:

```
.arabicChar {
    background: url(images/arabic-char.png);
}
```

The other option requires you using a chart like:
http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/cgi-bin/unicode.pl.cgi?start=0600&end=06FF

But then you must set the Font of the Button (via CSS) with a Font that contains those Arabic characters...